# How to query this nested XML in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

New to XML and Snowflake.  Can someone please give me an example of how I would query this nested XML data in Snowflake? Sample of the data is attached.  Specifically, I'd like to flatten this whole document (so I can see all columns) and I can put this data into Snowflake.

If someone can give me al example of this query in Snowflake I would appreciated it.  When I try to query this data I just get nulls except for the vehicle_number.  How would I query this XML to see all columns?

````
<pnet_get_performx_data_packet>
  <packet_id>4</packet_id>
  <more_data></more_data>
  <pxreport>
    <vehicle_number>5454</vehicle_number>
    <px_params>
      <long_idle_thresh>0</long_idle_thresh>
      <rpm_thresh>14</rpm_thresh>
      <over_speed>72</over_speed>
      <excess_speed>75</excess_speed>
    </px_params>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 13:47:16</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 14:06:08</ed>
      <so>8074162</so>
      <eo>8074162</eo>
      <et>0</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26651500</sf>
      <ef>26651500</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>0</els>
      <elm>0</elm>
      <fl1>59</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 14:06:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 14:16:08</ed>
      <so>8074162</so>
      <eo>8074162</eo>
      <et>96</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>96</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26651500</sf>
      <ef>26651500</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>8.5</els>
      <elm>61.5</elm>
      <fl1>61</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 14:16:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 14:17:54</ed>
      <so>8074162</so>
      <eo>8074162</eo>
      <et>107</et>
      <mt>13</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>94</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26651500</sf>
      <ef>26651500</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>7</els>
      <elm>14</elm>
      <fl1>62</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 14:17:54</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:06:08</ed>
      <so>8074162</so>
      <eo>8074489</eo>
      <et>2894</et>
      <mt>2715</mt>
      <or>1609</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>179</lit>
      <lic>10</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>4125</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>125</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26651500</sf>
      <ef>26655625</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>38</ba>
      <els>8</els>
      <elm>30.5</elm>
      <fl1>58</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>109</orlt>
      <orht>1500</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:06:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:11:26</ed>
      <so>8074489</so>
      <eo>8074491</eo>
      <et>318</et>
      <mt>108</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>210</lit>
      <lic>4</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655625</sf>
      <ef>26655625</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>2</ba>
      <els>7</els>
      <elm>10</elm>
      <fl1>60</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:11:26</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:12:42</ed>
      <so>8074491</so>
      <eo>8074491</eo>
      <et>76</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>76</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655625</sf>
      <ef>26655625</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>6.5</els>
      <elm>0</elm>
      <fl1>60</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:12:42</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:31:40</ed>
      <so>8074491</so>
      <eo>8074491</eo>
      <et>1137</et>
      <mt>3</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>1134</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>125</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>125</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655625</sf>
      <ef>26655750</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>7</els>
      <elm>20.5</elm>
      <fl1>61</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:31:40</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:38:02</ed>
      <so>8074491</so>
      <eo>8074491</eo>
      <et>21</et>
      <mt>18</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>3</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655750</sf>
      <ef>26655750</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>7</els>
      <elm>8</elm>
      <fl1>60</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:38:02</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:46:06</ed>
      <so>8074491</so>
      <eo>8074491</eo>
      <et>36</et>
      <mt>15</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>21</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655750</sf>
      <ef>26655750</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>13</els>
      <elm>13.5</elm>
      <fl1>58</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:46:06</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 15:51:18</ed>
      <so>8074491</so>
      <eo>8074499</eo>
      <et>312</et>
      <mt>175</mt>
      <or>72</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>137</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>250</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26655750</sf>
      <ef>26656000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>2</ba>
      <els>4</els>
      <elm>29</elm>
      <fl1>60</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>1</orlt>
      <orht>71</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 15:51:18</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 16:06:08</ed>
      <so>8074499</so>
      <eo>8074616</eo>
      <et>891</et>
      <mt>860</mt>
      <or>731</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>31</lit>
      <lic>2</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>2625</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26656000</sf>
      <ef>26658625</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>8</ba>
      <els>11</els>
      <elm>60</elm>
      <fl1>58</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>80</orlt>
      <orht>651</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 16:06:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 16:22:08</ed>
      <so>8074616</so>
      <eo>8074727</eo>
      <et>958</et>
      <mt>872</mt>
      <or>623</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>86</lit>
      <lic>3</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>1</sic>
      <gof>2250</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26658625</sf>
      <ef>26660875</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>13</ba>
      <els>9</els>
      <elm>52.5</elm>
      <fl1>56</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>29</orlt>
      <orht>594</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 16:22:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 16:29:18</ed>
      <so>8074727</so>
      <eo>8074727</eo>
      <et>0</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26660875</sf>
      <ef>26660875</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>0</els>
      <elm>0</elm>
      <fl1>56</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 16:29:18</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 16:55:48</ed>
      <so>8074727</so>
      <eo>8074727</eo>
      <et>127</et>
      <mt>6</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>121</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26660875</sf>
      <ef>26660875</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>6.5</els>
      <elm>19</elm>
      <fl1>56</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 16:55:48</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 17:06:08</ed>
      <so>8074727</so>
      <eo>8074813</eo>
      <et>621</et>
      <mt>596</mt>
      <or>495</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>25</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>1250</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26660875</sf>
      <ef>26662125</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>2</ba>
      <els>8</els>
      <elm>35</elm>
      <fl1>57</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>25</orlt>
      <orht>470</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 17:06:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 17:22:40</ed>
      <so>8074813</so>
      <eo>8074907</eo>
      <et>951</et>
      <mt>809</mt>
      <or>526</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>142</lit>
      <lic>6</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>875</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26662125</sf>
      <ef>26663000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>14</ba>
      <els>9</els>
      <elm>24.5</elm>
      <fl1>56</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>34</orlt>
      <orht>492</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 17:22:40</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 17:28:00</ed>
      <so>8074907</so>
      <eo>8074907</eo>
      <et>0</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26663000</sf>
      <ef>26663000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>0</els>
      <elm>0</elm>
      <fl1>56</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 17:28:00</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 17:41:26</ed>
      <so>8074907</so>
      <eo>8074908</eo>
      <et>101</et>
      <mt>22</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>79</lit>
      <lic>2</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26663000</sf>
      <ef>26663000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>9</els>
      <elm>15</elm>
      <fl1>57</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 17:41:26</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 18:06:08</ed>
      <so>8074908</so>
      <eo>8075098</eo>
      <et>1483</et>
      <mt>1343</mt>
      <or>1124</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>140</lit>
      <lic>2</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>3000</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26663000</sf>
      <ef>26666000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>9</ba>
      <els>7</els>
      <elm>41.5</elm>
      <fl1>55</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>49</orlt>
      <orht>1075</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 18:06:08</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 18:12:34</ed>
      <so>8075098</so>
      <eo>8075131</eo>
      <et>383</et>
      <mt>349</mt>
      <or>163</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>34</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>375</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26666000</sf>
      <ef>26666375</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>4</ba>
      <els>9.5</els>
      <elm>27</elm>
      <fl1>55</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>9</orlt>
      <orht>154</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 18:12:36</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 18:18:04</ed>
      <so>8075131</so>
      <eo>8075131</eo>
      <et>0</et>
      <mt>0</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26666375</sf>
      <ef>26666375</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>0</els>
      <elm>0</elm>
      <fl1>55</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 18:18:04</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 18:43:20</ed>
      <so>8075131</so>
      <eo>8075131</eo>
      <et>215</et>
      <mt>4</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>211</lit>
      <lic>1</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26666375</sf>
      <ef>26666375</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>0</ba>
      <els>5.5</els>
      <elm>16.5</elm>
      <fl1>57</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 18:43:20</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 18:46:54</ed>
      <so>8075131</so>
      <eo>8075142</eo>
      <et>213</et>
      <mt>213</mt>
      <or>64</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>375</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26666375</sf>
      <ef>26666750</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>7</ba>
      <els>0</els>
      <elm>21</elm>
      <fl1>58</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>7</orlt>
      <orht>57</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 18:46:54</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 19:06:08</ed>
      <so>8075142</so>
      <eo>8075239</eo>
      <et>1155</et>
      <mt>987</mt>
      <or>645</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>168</lit>
      <lic>9</lic>
      <sit>0</sit>
      <sic>0</sic>
      <gof>1250</gof>
      <vin></vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>26666750</sf>
      <ef>26668000</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>16</ba>
      <els>7.5</els>
      <elm>29</elm>
      <fl1>54</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>45</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>20</orlt>
      <orht>625</orht>
    </reportdata>
  </pxreport>
  <pxreport>
    <vehicle_number>6460</vehicle_number>
    <px_params>
      <long_idle_thresh>420</long_idle_thresh>
      <rpm_thresh>16</rpm_thresh>
      <over_speed>73</over_speed>
      <excess_speed>80</excess_speed>
    </px_params>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 13:50:22</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 13:58:28</ed>
      <so>4185526</so>
      <eo>4185526</eo>
      <et>33</et>
      <mt>6</mt>
      <or>0</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>27</sit>
      <sic>2</sic>
      <gof>0</gof>
      <vin>00000000000000000</vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>13375750</sf>
      <ef>13375750</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>12.5</els>
      <elm>22.5</elm>
      <fl1>81</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>60</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>0</orht>
    </reportdata>
    <reportdata>
      <sd>05/19/2022 13:58:28</sd>
      <ed>05/19/2022 13:59:56</ed>
      <so>4185526</so>
      <eo>4185528</eo>
      <et>87</et>
      <mt>81</mt>
      <or>1</or>
      <os>0</os>
      <es>0</es>
      <lit>0</lit>
      <lic>0</lic>
      <sit>6</sit>
      <sic>1</sic>
      <gof>125</gof>
      <vin>00000000000000000</vin>
      <lif>0</lif>
      <sif>0</sif>
      <sf>13375750</sf>
      <ef>13375875</ef>
      <nce>0</nce>
      <ct>0</ct>
      <cf>0</cf>
      <cd>0</cd>
      <tgv>0</tgv>
      <tgt>0</tgt>
      <tgf>0</tgf>
      <tgd>0</tgd>
      <sbt>0</sbt>
      <ba>1</ba>
      <els>13</els>
      <elm>29</elm>
      <fl1>80</fl1>
      <fl2>0</fl2>
      <ht>0</ht>
      <sg>60</sg>
      <pfs>0</pfs>
      <efl>0</efl>
      <oslt>0</oslt>
      <osht>0</osht>
      <orlt>0</orlt>
      <orht>1</orht>
    </reportdata> 
</pxreport>
</pnet_get_performx_data_packet>```
````

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve when you query this XML? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'd like to be able to view the entire table flattened.  So a column for packet_id, another for excess_speed, one for sd, etc.  In other words I need to know how to flatten the whole document and query each group.

Comment: There is a very similar example here that might help you:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-QUERY-NESTED-XML-DATA-IN-SNOWFLAKE

Comment: I assume that each repeated group (<reportdata>) should be its own row but what do you want to happen to the non-repeated attributes (everything before the first <reportdata>)? Add them to every row, ignore them, something else?

Comment: I'd like to add the items before <reportdata> and display them repeated for each detail row in <reportdata>.